# Error Message When Using ArrayList<>();

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, arraylist, integer

I am trying to create a program in eclipse that uses an ArrayList. The problem I am having is that whenever I try and create a new list-

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I get an error saying that I cannot use <> for source level below 1.7. I tried to fix it by just clicking on the error and changing the source level, but then I get an error when I try to run the program saying there is no main method.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a main method?

Comment: yes i do. i don't know why i get this error

Comment: There is also a red exclamation mark on top of the project folder and it says that my project has errors although none are marked within the code

Comment: try `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

So your problem now is the main method. You've fixed the compilation error so now Eclipse is trying to run the program. Make sure you're actually trying to run a class with a main method, the class compiles, and the method's signature is correct. Each keyword is important, not just the name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of what you should write :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```